# Embed Guvnor or Other Drools Editors into Java Standalone Program

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor

I am developing a java standalone program which uses drools engine to calculation. I want the user can change the rules on this program. Hence, I plan to embed a drools editor in this java application. After google, I found Guvnor can be used in java webapp, but there is little information about how to embed Guvnor to java standalone, someone said it is challenged. http://drools-moved.46999.n3.nabble.com/How-to-integrate-Guvnor-GUI-in-a-test-app-td1595617.html

So I am not sure should I continue to researching on Guvnor. Is there any tutorial to guide embedding Govnor in standalone? If it is impossible, is there any alternative library I can use? By the way, my program will be used in commercial, so before I choose library, I have to check its license.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Martijn, I found guvnor cannot be used in standalone program. Finally, I use itext which support java editor. It could identify java key word and change colors of those words.